# Firebase Cloud Firestore subcollection rule permission-denied

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

My web app fetch some documents via query with two constraints:

```
const readReviews = async (gsin: string) => {
    const res = [];

    const ref = collectionGroup( db, 'reviews' );
        const constraints = [
        where('gsin', '==', gsin),
        orderBy( 'timestamp', 'asc' ),
    ];

    const q = query( ref, ...constraints );
    const querySnapshot = await getDocs(q);

    querySnapshot.forEach( (doc) => {
        res.push( doc.data() );
    } );
  
    return res;
}
```

And my Firestore rule is

```
match /products/{gsin} {
    allow read;
    //..,
  
    match /reviews/{reviewId} {
        allow read;
        
        //...
    }
}
```

When I fetch data from the web app. it just display a 'permission-denied' error.

I tried to make another rule to focus on reviews subcollection: permission-denied

```
match /reviews/{reviewId} {
    allow read;
}
```

When I allow read to everyone it makes the fetch just right

```
match /{document=**} {
    allow read;
}
```

So I think it is a rule-focused issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As in step 2 of the documentation on [securely querying documents in collection groups](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#secure_and_query_documents_based_on_collection_groups), you need a **top-level** rule of this format:

```
match /{path=**}/[COLLECTION_ID]/{doc}
```

This is needed because a collection group matches collections with the given name no matter where they exist in the database.

So add a top-level rule like this:

```
match /(path=**)/reviews/{reviewId} {
    allow read;
}
```